# JWPlayer 6 playlist - interaction between internal JWPlayer playlist and external dynamic playlist

Tags: dynamic, external, jwplayer, internal, playlist

I am using a count function that queries a MySQL database.  Each result creates an a href  link that calls the JWPlayer individually with one video filename.

The list of results is my playlist.  It is external to JWPlayer.

I want to pass this list into JWPlayer to use as its internal playlist so it will play all the videos in sequence, and so the user can navigate forward and backward in the list.

Both playlists will have exactly the same videos in them, and in the same order.

I also want the user to be able to click on any of the links in my external playlist to play that file and then continue the playlist from that point onwards.

Can the JWPlayer internal playlist be controlled externally?

For example, could I create an RSS feed file that would be updated whenever I clicked on one of my external playlist links?

Would JWPlayer reload the updated RSS file?

Does it matter if the RSS file has the same filename?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Kind regards,

Kyle

Comment: Can't you load the data externally and use jquery to modify JWPlayer's playlist?

Comment: You could load the playlist into the JW Player as either rss or just straight json.